# Bypass google firebase email verification continue screen

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to direct my users directly to a page in my application and bypass the "Continue" screen that google firebase provides when verifying user emails.

We have cases where users aren't clicking "Continue" and try to go back to login, which results in no user having been created in the database yet.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify that page. If you need to run some custom actions like redirecting user then it'll be best to host your own webpage, verify the link using Firebase SDK and then proceed.

Checkout the documentation on creating [custom email action handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) for more information.